# cypress-file-upload zip file in angular solution not working

Tags: angular, cypress

I am trying to upload a file in angular solution using cypress.
Using this plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)

[image]

**Here the code I used**

```js
const filepath = 'test-20210816-071154.zip'

cy.get(".mat-focus-indicator.mat-tooltip-trigger.add-button.positive-button.small-icon-button.mat-icon-button").attachFile(filepath)
```

**That test case is passing but file upload is not working!**
Whereas same code I use to upload here
[image]

it is working.

```js
cy.get("#fileUpload").attachFile(filepath)
```

So my question - does cypress-file-upload plugin really work for angular solution? if so, how can it be?

using this code
cy.get('input[data-placeholder="type diagram name"]).attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' }).trigger('change', {force:true})
it focuses on field not on import icon
[image]

I finally get exact input direction, which is input[type="file"] and is in hidden assured by developer

cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(filepath,{ mimeType: 'application/zip' }); used that - not uploading rather "invalid JSON file" message showing. What I can do now?

Comment: Is the file in your project folder?

Comment: yes, the file in fixture folder and placing there similarly the 2nd mention website is working..but the angular not taking it

Comment: That's not how you use the `cypress-file-upload` package, please read the documentation.

Comment: You are correct. The steps I mentioned for manual part. Obviously, that plugin works not in same way :)

Comment: @Electron Unfortunately its not working with your solution because here is a development fault. I just talked to dev, he assured that the input for icon has vanished intentionally for different reason here the input we see is for field which is not using for import it will just show the name after import and also its not clickable like that icon.. However they will try to bring that input again. I hope your solution might work after that change made. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attachFile()` should be used on an `<input>` (2nd example does).

But in the Angular app you attached to a `<button>`.

Need to go a div or two up the tree (hard to tell exactly from info given)

```js
cy.get('button.add-button')
  .parent()
  .prev()
  .find('input')
  .attachFile(filepath)
```

That's a guess, if not ok post more html showing the `<input>` left of the button on the screen.

---

#### Example using Angular

Note `{ subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' }` is required here (may or may not for your app).

```js
it('uploads a file in an Angular app', () => {

  cy.viewport(1200,1000)
  cy.visit('https://kzrfaisal.github.io/#/afu')

  // Upload button is initially disabled
  cy.get('button').contains('Upload')
    .should('not.be.enabled')

  // Attach the file
  cy.get('input[name="files[]"]').eq(0)
    .attachFile('Asmara, Eritrea.jpg', { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
    .trigger('change', {force:true})

  // Upload button is active
  cy.get('button').contains('Upload')
    .should('be.enabled')
    .click()

  cy.contains('Successfully Uploaded !')
    .should('be.visible')
})
```

---

#### Addtional note from Humayun Rana

**By the way - the following code works-**

```js
const filepath = 'xxx.zip'
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(filepath,{ mimeType: 'application/zip' });
```

if using xpath -

```js
cy.xpath('xpath to input').attachFile(filepath,{ mimeType: 'application/zip' });
```

Comment: I tried with your code    cy.get('button.add-button')
  .parent()
  .prev()
  .find('input')
  .attachFile(filepath)   not getting the upload done. However, I again updated the image with more detail view. Can you pls look into which would be right command. Thanks

Comment: image with input updated. please have a look

Comment: I think probably `cy.get('input[data-placeholder="type diagram name"]).attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' }).trigger('change', {force:true})`.

Comment: Above code is focusing on field not import icon. See the image I attached the image at last of the desc.

Comment: It won't work if you `attachFile()` to the icon.

Comment: Look your second example (the one that works) - you `attachFile()` to the `<input>` not the "Choose File" button you have circled.